# Find the number of points of discontinuity of $f(x)=\lfloor 5\sin x+12\cos x\rfloor$ in $x\in[-2\pi,2\pi]$

Tags: calculus, functions

**Question:**

Find the number of points of discontinuity of $f(x)=\lfloor 5\sin x+12\cos x\rfloor$ in $x\in[-2\pi,2\pi]$, where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function.

**My Attempt:**

$f(x)=\lfloor 13\sin(x+\alpha)\rfloor$, where $\alpha=\arcsin\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)$

And $-2\pi+\alpha\le x+\alpha\le2\pi+\alpha$

$f(x)$ will be discontinuous when $\sin (x+\alpha)$ is either of $0, \pm\frac1{13}, \pm\frac2{13},...,\pm\frac{12}{13},\pm1$.

Thus, I am getting $104$ points of discontinuity. The answer given is $102$.

Please share your take. Thanks.

Comment: There may be no discontinuities at the endpoints since the function is defined beyond them. You only need one directional continuity there

Comment: I already discounted one end point. Other is included, I think @BarryCarter

Comment: The summits have a discontinuity point, but not the valleys, that's $2$ points removed. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/avieteu8mj

Comment: $sin(x + \alpha) = -1$ is probably not a discontinuity as the function will be higher than that on both the sides so the greatest integer smaller or equal will be $-1$ on both the sides.

Comment: @zwim thankyou very much

Comment: @Rishi thanks a lot